# The procedure entry point fclose could not be located

Tags: c, ruby, windows, api, fclose

I've recently built a Ruby C extension wrapping the library gorilla-audio. The library is simple enough, clean code, memory is accounted for, etc. However when I try to load the library into ruby it throws an error that reads:

> The procedure entry point fclose could not be located in the dynamic link
>
> library mscvrt-ruby191.dll.

I have included `stdio.h` in my source, as has gorilla-audio, not sure what is happening. Any ideas?

Could this be due to building my extension with `mingw/msys` but loading it into a windows application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in case another person gets something like this; actually, it's two answers:

1. Don't cross compile, and
2. I needed to link the `msvcrt` library, as it holds all the default functions like `fclose()`, etc.

However, it didn't matter, because I  was cross compiling anyways; I'll have to convert Ruby headers and some of it's source to C++ to be able to make Ruby C extensions with Visual Studio.